# Dynamically memory allocation

Tags: c++

It is code to reverse the values as they entered.When I am running the following code. It is taking 8 inputs only. After that it is not printing anything.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int n;
cin>>n;
int *p = new int(sizeof(int)*n);
int q = n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>*p;
    p++;
}
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    cout<<*p<<" ";
    p--;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is not printing anything"? Executing it, it is nearly printing your desired output, except the first element is always `0`so it will never print the last: `n=8`, output=`0 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 `

Comment: It was not printing values inside of 2nd loop. Now i got the solution. It should be int *p = new int[n]; It should be an array. Thank you

Comment: `new int(sizeof(int)*n)` allocates a *single* `int` and initializes it to `sizeof(int)*n`. You need to spend more time with [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), find new tutorials, or go through your class-notes again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following answer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int n;
cin>>n;
int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
int q = n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>*p;
    p++;
}
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{

    p--;
    cout<<*p<<" ";
}
free(p);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `malloc` and `free` in C++ is almost *never* a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> ```

(Not related to the title, but `using namespace std` is bad practice that can lead to breakage when switching compilers, for example. Better write the `std::` prefix when needed, such as `std::cin >>`.

> ```
> int main() {
> int n;
> cin>>n;
> int *p = new int(sizeof(int)*n);
> ```

The above is allocating a single int object, whose value is `sizeof(int)*n`, and  `p` points to that integer. You probably mean:

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n); // bad style
... at the end:
free(p);
```

But using `malloc` in C++ is a bad idea, unless you want to go closer to the operating system for educational purposes.

Slightly better is to use `new`, which besides allocating the objects also calls their constructors (but nothing is constructed for basic types such as `int`).

```
int *p = new int[n]; // so-so style
... at the end:
delete [] p;
```

The above is not the best practice because it requires manual memory management. Instead, it is recommended to use smart pointers or containers whenever possible:

```
std::vector<int> p(n);
// continue with the code, just like with the pointers
```

Or allocate the individual elements only when needed.

```
std::vector<int> p;
p.reserve(n);  // this is a minor optimization in this case
// ...
   if (int value; std::cin >> value)
      // This is how to add elements:
      p.push_back(value); 
   else
      std::cin.clear();
```

This looks ok:

> ```
> int q = n;
> for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
> {
>     cin>>*p;
>     p++;
> }
> ```

But this is broken. When the loop starts, `p` points after the last element. The following `*p` dereferences a pointer which goes past the last element:

> ```
> for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
> {
>     cout<<*p<<" ";
>     p--;
> }
> ```

Replacing the order of pointer decrement and dereference avoids the crash:

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    p--;
    std::cout << *p << " ";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, there many issues here:

```
int *p = new int(sizeof(int)*n);
```

This memory allocation is wrong. It allocates n times sizeof(int) bytes, so if `int` is 4 bytes long it will allocates `n * 4` integers.

```
int q = n;
```

`q` variable is never used.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>*p;
    p++;
}
```

There is no need for pointer arithmetic here. It would be better to access the array in simple `p[i]` way.

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    cout<<*p<<" ";
    p--;
}
```

Same here...

```
return 0;
}
```

You allocated memory, but never deallocate. This will cause memory leaks.

A better, correct version of the program could be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int * p = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> p[i];
    }
    for (int i = (n - 1); i >= 0; --i)
    {
        cout << p[i] << ' ';
    }
    delete [] p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right that the issue is with the `new` expression, but it's not what you claim it is (if it was, it would allocate to many elements, and while that's wasteful it wouldn't lead to that many problems).

Comment: Please read the whole answer, starting from `... there many issues here:...`

Comment: But you don't really fix the `new` problem in the OP's code... `new int(n)` is semantically still incorrect and will again lead to UB and possible crashes.

Comment: True, how could I not see that before... Corrected.